# What's the maximum size of data is possible to insert for varchar(50);

Tags: mysql

I have to apply the restriction through the database that not more than 200kb of data can be inserted in the related field then what should be the varchar size.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store data larger than 64kb, you'll need to use the [TEXT or BLOB column types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html), as mysql has a [64kb limit for VARCHAR types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) in general.

For columns that will only store less than 64kb per row, you can use a VARCHAR, but the number in the parenthesis must be the maximum number of characters the column can take. However, note even then that large text can still be better in a TEXT or BLOB column if you're using innodb, as [innodb will store the contents of the TEXT/BLOB type away from the other columns](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,267596), to avoid hurting performance on scans of the table.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `varchar(8000)` as max for non-unicode character data. the number in varchar represents bytes. You can specify a maximum of 8000 which does not exceed your 200kb limit. The storage size is the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.

EDIT - Correction - From the comments below -

The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used." so depending on what else is in the row, it might be smaller than that

Comment: @bdonlan - Yes, you are right. Edited my answer to remove 2048 from varchar.

Comment: 8000 characters won't fit 200 kilobytes of data either :)

Comment: @bdonlan - Yes, but this is the max you can set for a varchar. or need to use varchar(max) in which case there is no way of setting max size. But yes, your answer seems more reasonable. :) +1

Comment: As indicated in the link I posted, 64k (65535) is actually the limit, not 8000 - but indeed it's not sufficient for the questioner's needs :)

Comment: @bdonlan - I thought that is the limit when setting varchar(max). Well, this is good to know. Will edit my answer to put 65535 as limit

Comment: "The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used." so depending on what else is in the row, it might be smaller than that.